# Calculate closing date with openedon date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm doing reccuring deposit calculations, When open reccuring deposit account on that time itself i have set opening date as today's date using before_save. I dono how to calculate account maturity date. Because, in my reccuring deposit i have many fields in my dropdown like 6months, 1year, 2years ... upto 5 years. According to that openedon date i have to close that account or renew it on that maturity date itself.

i have use the below code for openedon date

```
  before_save :set_openedon   

  def set_openedon
    self.openedon = Date.today
  end
```

**for example:**

1. for first rd account  openedon date is 13/05/2013 and maturity date must be 13/05/2014 for one year.
2. for second rd account  openedon date is 15/09/2012 and maturity date must be 15/09/2014 for two years.

like that i have to calculate maturity date for all the accounts. But i dono how to do.
Kindly help me.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you store the recurring interval, i.e. "6months, 1year, 2years ... upto 5 years"?

Comment: in a drop down named noy (no.of.years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something alike:

```
def calculate_dates
    self.openedon = Date.today
    case self.noy
    when '1'
      self.md = self.openedon+1.year
    when '2'
      self.md = self.openedon+2.years
    when '3'
      self.md = self.openedon+3.years
    when '4'
      self.md = self.openedon+4.years
    when '5'
      self.md = self.openedon+5.years
    else
      self.md = self.openedon+6.months
    end
end
```

Comment: Zlatin Zlatev: Thank you so much i have got the required result just now.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has quite easy-to-use date operators:

```
Date.parse('13/05/2013') + 1.year
# => Tue, 13 May 2014
Date.parse('15/09/2012') + 2.years
# => Mon, 15 Sep 2014
```

Same for `6.months`, etc.

Comment: Uri Agassi can you please help me the below code is not working    before_save :calculate_md
  def calculate_md
    if self.noy == '1'
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 1.year
    elsif self.noy == '2'
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 2.years
    elsif self.noy == '3'
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 3.years
    elsif self.noy == '4'
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 4.years
    elsif self.noy == '5'
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 5.years
    else
      self.md = Date.parse(self.openedon) + 6.months
    end    
  end

Comment: Uri Agassi: Thanks for your support. Finally, i got the maturity date just now.